# python pint : Create a "pace" metric from velocity metrics

Tags: python, pint

Using the `pint` library in python - It has support for unit conversions, which work great.

For example:

```
units.Quantity(2, "mph").to("kph")
```

I would like to understand how I could define a unit `pacem` - which would be "minutes per mile", or `pacek` which would be "minutes per km"

This feels like it should be do-able in the units definitions, without having to write any python code at all, in the same way as I could write

```
units.define("rps = revolution / second")
```

Comment: Isn't pace just time over distance?  Yup, as you said, so the definition should follow from your definition of `rps`

Comment: `(1/units.Quantity('10 kph')).to('pace')` works for me after running `units.define("pace = minutes / kilometers")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those units scale with the inverse of each other, i.e. speed is inversely proportional to pace.  Hence I seem to need to transform first.  Something like:

```
import pint
units = pint.UnitRegistry()
units.define("pace = minutes / kilometers")
speed = units.Quantity('10 kph')
print((1/speed).to('pace'))
```

outputs `6.0 pace`.

Comment: i was thinking it might be possible to do this in the unit definition itself.. but tbh this actually fits the bill nicely. thanks!